# bash script Incremement array index inside expect code

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, expect

This is my code that I have embedded in some bash script.

```
VAR=$(expect -c 'expect {  
       "name:" { send "'${Array[pos]}'"\r" ; exp_continue}  
       "hello" {send "hello\r" ; exp_continue}  
    }
```

However the required value passed is a string that is stored in the array Array. If it gets it wrong it will continue to ask for "name:", the correct value is always in Array.
How can I incrememnt pos each time so that I will eventually hit the right entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `${Array[pos++]}` that will post-increment each time.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, and ++pos but it doesnt increment. If I put a hard coded array index in there I can see that working. Its seems as though doing that as part of expect code doesnt seem to incrememnt

Comment: Since you put that outside of the single quotes, it's actually the shell doing that work.